# Trying to set up a multilingual website with Kentico URL structure

Tags: kentico

I'm trying to configure a multilingual website with Kentico.

**The ideal solution is to have the url structure as:**

- domain.com/path/to/page/
- domain.com/de-de/path/to/page/

**However in the Kentico documentation I only see:**

- domain.com/en-us/path/to/page/
- domain.com/de-de/path/to/page/

Answer (score 1):

This is certainly possible. You don't have to use language prefixes. In fact, if you don't force them, either the default or the culture stored in visitor's cookie will be used to determine site culture.

As mentioned in [docs](https://docs.kentico.com/k11/configuring-kentico/managing-sites/configuring-settings-for-sites/settings-urls-and-seo) for **Use language prefix for URLs**:

> If enabled, the system generates page URLs with language prefixes. A
>   language prefix is a subdirectory inserted into the URL. The name of
>   the prefix matches the culture code (or culture alias) of the content
>   culture selected on the website.

After this, you also need to enable **Allow URLs without language prefixes** so that Kentico does not autoredirect.

Comment: does this allow you to use both `domain.com` (for english) and `domain.com/de-de` though?  I believe the if you check the box, it does one or the other and does not allow both.

Comment: So it works initially, but when you click on an english page it puts in /en-us/. I'm looking for it to be domain.com/page/ always and domain.com/de-de/ for german pages.

Comment: forgot to mention that you also need to enable 'Allow URLs without language prefixes'. This way Kentico will not autoredicted. I updated answer.